# existence of a limit for $f(x,y)=\int_{x}^{y} e^{-t^2} dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the existence of the limit for ||(x,y)||-> (0,0) of the function $f(x,y)=\int_{x}^{y} e^{-t^2} dt$

Can I use polar coordinates?

Comment: Assume $y>x$, then the integral is bounded below by zero and above by $|y-x|e^{-x^2}$. So what is the limit when $||(x,y)||\to 0$?

Comment: Simply use the fact that, for all $t \geq 0$, $e^{-t} \leq 1$. It follows that :

$$ \Bigg\vert \int_{x}^{y} e^{-t^2} \, dt \Bigg\vert \leq \vert y - x \vert $$